# Why is Excel / Word 2013 starting invisible?

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office

Our Company recently upgraded to Office 2013 since we want to use SharePoint 2013.

We had several issues with the new Office Version but Microsoft has already solved some of them.

Anyways, one thing sitll grinds my gears: 
Excel or Word **sometimes** starts invisible. It is visible in the Taskbar but the window doesnt pop up. I can click on the Icon in the taskbar but it doesn't change anything. The only way i figured out to show the window, is to use <kbd>**[Windows]**</kbd> + <kbd>[Arrow Keys]</kbd>.

I can't tell the constellation why this is happening but most of the time it is if there isn't already another instance of the program running.

I don't have Office 2013 at home to reconstruct this but I have seen this on different Computers at our Office.

- Now does anybody know about this issue?
- What can I do about it?
- Is it known to Microsoft?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using the release version of Office 2016. It seems there a [many others with the same problem.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0deec0a9-d08f-48c6-9cfc-c9d7fb695017/office-2013-invisible-windows?forum=officeitpro)

Comment: I am having this problem as well. It is *invisible* and not off screen. How do I know? I can grab the window and move it, at which point it reappears.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it's invisible, it's just starting off screen somewhere.  Perhaps on a second monitor that is no longer there (or moved virtually to the other side).  The **[Windows] + [Arrows Keys]** just moves the window onscreen where you can see it.

Alternatively, you could ***hover*** the mouse over the ***icon*** on the ***task bar***, **right click** on the ***preview window*** and then **select Move** (if Move is grayed out, ***select restore*** and repeat).  Then, hit any **[Arrow Key]** (this will attach your mouse to the window caption bar) then **move your mouse** (without clicking anything) until the window shows up on screen.

By doing this you can figure out what side of the screen the application is opening up (not that knowing helps much).  Excel should just show up where ever you had it last, **but** it will not remember it's location if you snap it to the sides or top of the screen (which is what you were doing); ***It will only remember the Normal View size and position of the window***.

Comment: P.S. Thanks for the **[Windows] + [Arrows Keys]** tip.

Comment: I disagree--I believe it is in fact invisible. My evidence: if the window is active and over another window (but I can still see the other window b/c the Office window is invisible), the mouse cursor will change according to what I'm hovering over on the Office window-not at all related to the application I'm seeing. Also, if I press ALT, the accelerator keys appear over top of the application showing through on that screen.  I don't believe either of these would happen if the window was just somewhere off screen. Regardless, this brings the window back (but doesn't really fix the problem).

Comment: @glancep - I think you have a different issue;  it sounds more like the screen updating is off or you are having screen refreshing issues.  Trust me, when an app is invisible/hidden there is nothing that you can do in the windows GUI to make it visible;  It wont even show up on the task bar and can only be made visible using code (VBA or other) .  I think it basically comes down to the different meanings behind the syntax that we are both using to describe the problem.

Comment: @glancep - Try *opening* the **VBA Editor** `(Alt+F11)`, in the **immediate window** `(Ctrl+G)` *type* `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and then *hit* **Enter**.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this bug is to click the Taskbar icon for the new (invisible) window while it's active, which minimizes the window, then click it again to restore it. Then it becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and it's definitely an invisible window, not off-screen (see workaround below).
It only happens in specific circumstances: when opening a second word doc from a sharepoint/office 365 location, the second doc gets a taskbar icon, but no visible content, so the first doc is still visible (but the second doc is invisibly in front of it).

The workaround is to click the minimise button on the first doc. Nothing will appear to happen because it's the invisible second doc window that receives the click event. Then select the icon on the task bar to make it reappear, properly visible.